Basic player platformer code but can't use directional based animations in godot
I was trying to use the default script for a 2D player controller, but now I'm struggling to make a different animation based on the direction variable in the script.
The error message says that I need 2 parameters for input.get_axis() in my if statement.  I only put 1 so that when I go left the sprite faces left but it's not working.
extends CharacterBody2D

const SPEED = 300.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    $AnimatedSprite2D
    var direction := Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity += get_gravity() * delta

    # Handle jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        if direction == Input.get_axis("ui_left"):
            set_animation("default")

        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()

I've tried looking it up but I can't find anything.

Hi Liam, welcome to Stack Overflow! If you get the chance, it would be awesome if you could edit the question to point out a specific problem with the code, or just something that isn't behaving how you expect. Including your error message helps greatly. By doing that, it becomes a lot easier to give specific solutions for you. Also, check out either of Godot's major Discord communities -- you can get great advice and ask questions in real-time! It looks like you might be having trouble with Input.get_axis() and using Vector2.x with comparison operators like < or >.

Have a look at the documentation of Input.getAxis : Docs
The function always needs two parameters. One for negative and one for positive. The result is a float between -1 and 1 which represents how far the axis is moved in one of the specific directions.
for your direction variable this means: If the user fully moves the stick to the left, direction will be -1, since you declared this your negative action. And full right would be 1.
In conclusion, if you want to check, if the player moves to the left your comparison should look like this:
if direction < 0:


I am going to assume that you only have animations for left and right, as this seems like the start of a platformer game.
With Input.get_axis(), a float is stored in your variable direction. If you go left, direction is set to -1, and if you go right, the direction is set to 1. If you don't press anything, the direction is set to 0.
So, if you want to change the animation based on direction, you can check if direction < 0 for left, or if direction > 0 for right. You'll additionally want to do this outside of checking for a jump if you want animations where the character is running/idle.

Now just some other points to help you on your way.
You are referencing $AnimatedSprite2D in your _physics_process, but you're not storing it anywhere, so you can't actually use it. You'll want to have something like this:
var animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D.
Because of how things are loaded in Godot, you'll also need to move this outside of the _physics_process and into the main body of the script. If you don't, your script will try to load the AnimatedSprite2D every physics frame (60 times per second). So at the top where you have your constants, you'll need to add the @onready tag:
@onready var animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D.
This will allow you to change your animations using animated_sprite.play(<animation_name>).
Now, with the gravity, you are currently adding it to the velocity directly, and not the velocity's y component. Velocity uses a Vector2 which has an x and a y component. You can think of anything that goes from left to right as the x part, and anything that goes up or down as the y part.
So, here I would use velocity.y += get_gravity() * delta to make gravity work up and down.
